CLI Software used by professionals instead of OBS
Time ago I went on a website of this super broadcast software that could be ran via command line and used by various professionals on the field. Searching via gpt or google don't bring any good result.
It was capable of applying transitions, effects and everything a bit like obs does but spanned also in multi core - multi cpu/gpu/servers environments.
I don't remember the name, I remember it was open and available on various os mostly I think Linux (for sure) and Windows (?).
Can you guys help me find this out?
Thanks

Are you talking about ffmpeg?

My first thought was ffmpeg too.

Nope I do know well ffmpeg, but was different. Damn, if I remembered the name...

Well, this is more of a "guess what author has on mind" than "software recommendation" generally, as the description is vague and fits almost any of such software, including the mentioned most popular one by far.
